# SFML Failed to load image from memory, no data provided

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, sfml

I'm using SFML with C++ in VS2012. In debug console i have error "failed to load image from memory, no data provided" and "failed to create texture, invalid size <0x0>".

My main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>


using namespace std;

sf::Image LoadImageFromResource(const std::string& name)
{
    HRSRC rsrcData = FindResource(NULL, name.c_str(), RT_RCDATA);

    DWORD rsrcDataSize = SizeofResource(NULL, rsrcData);

    HGLOBAL grsrcData = LoadResource(NULL, rsrcData);

    LPVOID firstByte = LockResource(grsrcData);


    sf::Image image;
    image.loadFromMemory(firstByte, rsrcDataSize);


    return image;
}

int main()
{      
    sf::Image SpriteSheetWalkRes = LoadImageFromResource("IDB_PNG1");
    sf::Texture SpriteSheetWalk;
    SpriteSheetWalk.loadFromImage(SpriteSheetWalkRes);
}
```

My Resource.rc

```
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

#include "afxres.h"

#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_RUS)
LANGUAGE LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif

IDB_PNG1            RCDATA           "F:\\(...)\\test_player.png"

#endif 

#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif
```

My resource.h

```
#define IDB_PNG1                        101

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        102
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Please mention the location of code where it is causing the problem and error details.

Comment: I dont know location, im have error in debug console, but i think this part.
---------------------------------------------------sf::Image SpriteSheetWalkRes = LoadImageFromResource("IDB_PNG1");

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a resource editor or dumpbin.exe and check if your resource was linked into the binary.

Comment: Yea, i have my image in resources.
http://storage5.static.itmages.ru/i/15/1211/h_1449840939_8492332_21acd772f8.png